# PutItem in DynamoDB table by CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way to put items in a DynamoDB table using CloudFormation ?
Something similar to the code in this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)

In the parameter of the template I give the user the possibility to put the values, then I need to insert these values into the table.

Comment: No there is not. I think the proper question though is why would you want to?

Comment: I am working on a solution similar to this [one](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/ebs-snapshot-scheduler/latest/ebs-snapshot-scheduler.pdf) published by AWS. @Robo I used a custom Resource but I have a problem that the resource is not creating, it shows creation in progress continuously

Comment: A custom resource is the only way to achieve this, since cloudformation has no way to provide data for your resources or execute arbitrary API call.

Comment: @jens could you provide your comment with more details in an answer please.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The way to achieve this would be to utilize Custom Resources for this.

Here a Cloudformation template which utilizes an inline Lambda for this task.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: dynamodbAccessRole
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - dynamodb:*
              Resource: "*"
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - logs:*
              Resource: "*"
  InitFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: >
          const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
          const response = require("cfn-response");
          const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(event,null,2));
              var params = {
                TableName: event.ResourceProperties.DynamoTableName,
                Item:{
                    "id": "abc123"
                }
            };
          docClient.put(params, function(err, data) { if (err) {
            response.send(event, context, "FAILED", {});
          } else {
            response.send(event, context, "SUCCESS", {});
          }
          });
          };
      Handler: index.handler
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ LambdaRole , "Arn" ]
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      Timeout: 60
  DynamoDB:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
  InitializeDynamoDB:
    Type: Custom::InitFunction
    DependsOn: DynamoDB
    Properties:
      ServiceToken:
         Fn::GetAtt: [ InitFunction , "Arn" ]
      DynamoTableName:
        Ref: DynamoDB
```

Comment: could you please provide the function code separetly in Python 2.7?

Comment: saldy no, I do not know any python or how to code lambdas in python.

Comment: In the sample provided, what triggers the function to run? I've used this successfully, but it only appears to run once. If I modify the seed data and redeploy it does not run the function, and therefore, does not populate my new seed data.

Comment: note that `nodejs4.3` is end-of-life now.  Use `nodejs10.x`

Comment: Note that there is an inline character limit of 4096 in which AWS wants you to just put the script up on S3 and reference it there

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the table might not be in the ACTIVE state when the Lambda function runs. DynamoDB tables are created asynchronously.

Comment: @MarkRichman this problem can be solved by adding a dependency on the table that is being initialized